# How to create new type by extending cmis:folder type in alfresco

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share, cmis

Thank you in advance for your help :)
I am new with alfresco and don't know how to do stuff
Now My Problem is i want to extend cmis:foder and want to create my own folder
with extra property's
Now what i have done up till now is
`fdModel.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<model name="fd:contentmodel" xmlns="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0">
   <description>My Content Model</description>
   <author>Vishnu</author>
   <version>1.0</version>

   <imports>
      <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0" prefix="d"/>
      <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0" prefix="cm"/>
      <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/cmis/1.0/cs01" prefix="cmis"/>
   </imports>

   <namespaces>
      <namespace uri="testing.model" prefix="fd"/>
   </namespaces>

   <types>
      <type name="fd:folder">
         <title>My Folder</title>
         <parent>cmis:folder</parent>
         <properties>
            <property name="fd:tablename">
               <title>Table Name</title>
               <type>d:text</type>
               <default></default>
            </property>
            <property name="fd:recordid">
               <title>Record ID</title>
               <type>d:text</type>
               <default></default>
            </property>
            <property name="fd:value">
               <title>Value</title>
               <type>d:text</type>
               <default></default>
            </property>
         </properties>
      </type>
   </types>
</model>
```

`web-client-config-adempiere-custom.xml`

```
<alfresco-config>
    <config evaluator="node-type" condition="fd:folder">
        <property-sheet>
            <separator name="sep" display-label="Properties" component-generator="HeaderSeparatorGenerator"  show-in-edit-mode="false"/>
            <show-property name="fd:tablename"/>
            <show-property name="fd:recordid"/>
            <show-property name="fd:value"/>
        </property-sheet>
    </config>

    <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="Content Wizards">
        <content-types>
            <type name="fd:folder"/>
        </content-types>
    </config>

    <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="Action Wizards">
        <subtypes>
            <type name="fd:folder"/>
        </subtypes>
    </config>

</alfresco-config>
```

and put above two files on path `\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\extension`
and add entry in type to make new type available on alfresco in file

```
share-config-custom
<types>
     <type name="trx:transferTarget">
        <subtype name="trx:fileTransferTarget" />
     </type>
     <type name="cmis:folder">
         <subtype name="fd:folder" />
     </type>
     <type name="fd:folder">
     </type>
</types>
```

and put above two files on path `\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\web-extension`
but unfortunately not able to see my new type fd:folder in type list in alfresco

Note that if i use cm:folder insted of cmis:folder it is Working like a charm

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you don't really want to extend cmis:folder, but rather cm:folder

The default folder type is cm:folder.

You would need to extend it like this:

```
  <type name="fd:folder">
     <title>My Folder</title>
     <parent>cm:folder</parent>
     <properties>
        <property name="fd:tablename">
           <title>Table Name</title>
           <type>d:text</type>

        </property>
        <property name="fd:recordid">
           <title>Record ID</title>
           <type>d:text</type>

        </property>
        <property name="fd:value">
           <title>Value</title>
           <type>d:text</type>

        </property>
     </properties>
  </type>
```

And the types in share:

```
<types>
     <type name="trx:transferTarget">
        <subtype name="trx:fileTransferTarget" />
     </type>
     <type name="cm:folder">
         <subtype name="fd:folder" />
     </type>
</types>
```

The web-client-config-adempiere-custom.xml is only needed if you are using the old explorer interface. Since you are a new user, this is probably not the case.

Comment: Thank you for your help :), but i know it will work with cm:folder (which i have mentioned in my question), and i want to make the same thing by using cmis:folder

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you want your own properties when using CMIS you do not need to extend cmis:folder. cmis:folder maps to cm:folder. Here is some more information: http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/concepts/content-model-cmis.html

Answer (score 0):

CMIS is just one way to expose the Alfresco data, so why should extensions to the content model be specific to CMIS?

In fact, when using CMIS you will automatically get references to `cmis:folder` when using `cm:folder` in your definition. Like when invoking:

```xml
<getTypeDefinition xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/">
    <repositoryId>...</repositoryId>
    <!-- Need F: for folder, D: for document -->
    <typeId>F:fd:folder</typeId>
</getTypeDefinition>
```

...will still nicely get you the following:

```xml
<getTypeDefinitionResponse xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/">
    <type ...>
        <id>F:fd:folder</id>
        ...
        <baseId>cmis:folder</baseId>
        <parentId>cmis:folder</parentId>
    </type>
</getTypeDefinitionResponse>
```

Also, Alfresco [explains](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/content-model-cmis.html):

> Alfresco maps its out-of-the-box types `cm:folder` and `cm:content` (as defined in the Alfresco ECM domain model) to CMIS Folder and CMIS Document, respectively. A folder can contain a mixture of documents and folders, allowing for a hierarchy of documents to be built. Through this, CMIS supports an implicit notion of parent to child, to which Alfresco maps its child association. Subtypes of `cm:folder` and `cm:content` are exposed as subtypes of CMIS Folder and Document, respectively.

So, to me, using `cm:folder` seems the right thing to do.